# Initialize the PriorityBlockingQueue with some predefined values

Tags: java, spring

I am using java with Spring IOC Framework .
I am working on a existing Application and i need to make a change to a certain piece of code

I have this line inside the core xml file

```
<bean name="SymQ" class="java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue" />
```

and this inside the java code

```
private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> SymQ;
```

Is it possible in any way that i can initialize the `SymQ` with some predefined values .
For example i need the PriorityBlockingQueue with some predefined values like `FF , DD , NJ`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List` as a constructor argument to [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
<bean name="symQ" class="java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>FF</value>
            <value>DD</value>
            <value>NJ</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Unrelated but note from the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

> The convention is to use the standard Java convention for instance field names when naming beans.

In this case the bean name becomes `symQ`

Comment: Thank you very much , should i use util:list  or java:util:list

Comment: Use `util:list` - it's standard `Spring`. In fact once you have the namespace defined you can just use `list` as above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` to call a method on your `SymQ` bean (in particular, the `addAll` method).  Add some config like this after the bean is declared:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetObject" ref="SymQ"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="addAll"/>
   <property name="arguments">
      <list>
          <value>FF</value>
          <value>DD</value>
          <value>NJ</value>
      </list>
   </property>      
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you received are both correct from the how to point of view. However in my experience design is largely undervaluated in programming and I was the first one to underestimate its importance.

The fact that you need to add default data to the queue in the application context suggests you are working with a level of abstraction that is too low.

You would better create a Symq class which exposes your business methods and which is backed by a priority queue. In the constructor of Symq you will initialize the queue by adding some initial values. The constructor is the right place to initialize non lazy internal data structures